# Selected values for multiple select on Laravel Collective

Tags: php, laravel-5.7, laravelcollective

I've got a string value from a controller which is:

```
$pickedValues = "1,2";
```

So what I'm trying to do is set the multiple selected values on the view, here is the select code that I have right now:

```
{{Form::select("selection[]", $data, (isset($pickedValues)) ? array($pickedValues) : '',
        [
            "class"    => "multiple-select",
            "multiple",
        ])
}}
```

That problem that I'm getting right now that it is not displaying the selected options, but if I put the values manually like `array(1,2)` it works. I've tried setting it as `array((int)$pickedValues)` but it only displays the value 1.

Comment: Maybe you can use `explode(',' $pickedValues)` instead of `array($pickedValues)`...

Comment: I've tried that but the selected values still doesn't appear.

Comment: Did you correct my misspelled? `explode(',', $pickedValues)`, I forgot the comma...

Comment: Yeah thats what the first thing I did before doing (int).

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this problem, 
Try the value like this

```
array('1','2')
```

Comment: This is not dynamic. It's very likely that the string "1,2" get other contents like "9,27,2". So this isn't a good answer.